# Unable to cast resolved object to generic abstraction autofac C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, autofac

Hey I try to cast my object to interface which this object should implements. But during executing code I have following error:

> Unable to cast object of type GetTreeHandler to IQueryHandler, IQuery<Tree>.

Why? Everything seems to be ok.

Any idea without using dynamic?

QueryDispatcher

```
    public async Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Query can not be null.");
        }

        var handlerType = typeof (IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof (TResult));
        var handler = _context.Resolve(handlerType);

        IQueryHandler<IQuery<TResult>, TResult> castedHandler = (IQueryHandler<IQuery<TResult>, TResult>) handler;

        return (TResult) await castedHandler.ExecuteAsync(query);    
    }
```

GetTreeHandler

```
   public class GetTreeHandler : IQueryHandler<GetTree, Tree>
    {
        private readonly ProductContext _context;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public GetTreeHandler(ProductContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<Tree> ExecuteAsync(GetTree query)
            =>  await Task.FromResult(
                    _context.Trees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == query.Id)
                );
    }
```

**EDIT**

My current solution(partially works):

```
    public async Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(IQuery query) where TResult : class
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Query can not be null.");
        }

        var handlerType = typeof (IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof (TResult));
        var handler = _context.Resolve(handlerType);

        return await (Task<TResult>)                        
            handler.GetType()                               
                   .GetMethod("ExecuteAsync")               
                   .Invoke(handler, new object[]{query});   
    }
```

Why partially? 
Eg. handlers:

Doesn't work:

```
public class GetIndexesHandler : IQueryHandler<GetIndexes, IEnumerable<AssocIndexDto>>
```

Works:

```
public class GetIndexesHandler : IQueryHandler<GetIndexes,AssocIndexDto>
```

As you can see these two classes implements the same interface but with different second parameter type.

The problem is that Resolve method cannot find the registered service, but if I try to debug this code, I can see that the wanted service is registed correctly, but it can't be found.

Have you any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Nope it doesn't has. _context.Resolve returns me "object" type, and I can't execute "ExecuteAsync" method on "object" type, so I decide to cast it to  appropriate interface.

Comment: `GetTreeHandler` implement `IQueryHandler<GetTree, Tree>`, but not `IQueryHandler<IQuery<Tree>, Tree>`.

Comment: But the GetTree implements IQuery<Tree>, so it should be correct, isn't it?

Comment: Is there any chance to do this without using dynamic?

Comment: Let's say that I found solution, but I don't know if it's a good way to do this.
Especially I mean performance. Does the reflection mechanism use any dynamic types underlayer?

Comment: *But the GetTree implements IQuery<Tree>, so it should be correct, isn't it?* You do not show `IQueryHandler` definition, but from usage it look like `IQueryHandler<IQuery<Tree>, Tree>` should define `ExecuteAsync(IQuery<Tree>)`, thus it should be able to accept any `IQuery<Tree>` implementation, but yours `ExecuteAsync` can only accept `GetTree`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to cast an `IQueryHandler<GetTree, Tree>` to an `IQueryHandler<IQuery<Tree>, Tree>`, but that would only work when `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>` was specified as:

```
interface IQueryHandler<out TQuery, TResult>
```

Notice the `out` argument here.

The `out` keyword marks `TQuery` as an output argument. In case a generic type argument is marked as output argument, it allows us to cast the interface to something more generic. An `IEnumerable<string>` for instance can be casted to `IEnumerable<object>` since `IEnumerable<string>` will return strings, and they can be represented as objects.

For `in` arguments however, the opposite holds. When looking at an `Action<in T>` for intance, we are allowed to cast an `Action<BaseType>` to `Action<SubType>`, since the action would always be able to process `SubType`s as well. On the other hand, it would be impossible to cast `Action<BaseType>` to `Action<object>` since that would allow us to pass in a `string` to the action as well (since `string` is an `object`), but that would then obviously fail at runtime.

So casting an `IQueryHandler<GetTree, Tree>` to `IQueryHandler<IQuery<Tree>, Tree>` would only be possible if `TQuery` is marked with an `out` keyword, but clearly `TQuery` is an input argument. The CLR therefore forbids the conversion, since it could lead to errors at runtime.

In your case however, this problem would not exist, because you know that the passed in type always fits. But remember, the CLR is unable to check this, and is therefore blocking the conversion.

One solution is, as I [described](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) on my blog, to use the `dynamic` keyword as follows:

```
public async Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
{
    var handlerType = 
        typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
    dynamic handler = _context.Resolve(handlerType);
    return (TResult)await castedHandler.ExecuteAsync((dynamic)query);    
}
```

Another option is to specify and register a generic wrapper type that implements an interface that lacks the `TQuery` generic type. This way you can prevent using `dynamic` altogether:

```
public interface IWrapper<TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync(IQuery<TResult> query);
}

public async Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
{
    var wrapperType =
        typeof(Wrapper<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
    var wrapper = (IWrapper<TResult>)_context.Resolve(wrapperType);
    return wrapper.ExecuteAsync(query);
}

// Don't forget to register this type by itself in Autofac.
public class Wrapper<TQuery, TResult> : IWrapper<TResult>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler;
    public Wrapper(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler) { this.handler = handler; }
    Task<TResult> IWrapper<TResult>.ExecuteAsync(IQuery<TResult> query) =>
        this.handler.ExecuteAsync((TQuery)query);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I will try your solution, because it looks that make sense, but I maybe I found the solution, however it doesn't work properly. Would you like to take a look on my soltion? (Edit's section in question)

Comment: @bielu000: You have two options, both are given in my answer. Your option using reflection and `Invoke` will not work correctly, since `Invoke` will wrap any thrown exception with an `InvocationException` which will confuscate your log file and complicate handling specific exceptions (such as `ValidationException`s) from the business layer.

Comment: Edit up: It was my mistake that the handler wasn't found ;)Please do not bother yourself about it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to improve my solution, using yours.

Comment: Something is wrong with wprapper's registration in my container. It throws exception that the Wrapper has not been registered. 

But in my opinion I'm dooing it right: 
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(QueryBusWrapper<,>))
                   .As(typeof(IQueryBusWrapper<>))
                   .InstancePerDependency();

Comment: @bielu000 in my code example I placed tge comment "Don't forget to register this type by itself". It's the "by itself" bit that you did wrong. I think the syntax is ".AsSelf()" in Autofac.

Comment: Eh, you're absolutely right, I'm new in Autofac, so I didn't know "AsSelf()" method. Everything works fine. Thanks a lot.